# Rails 4.2 Namespace Routes Change after Initial Load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

Hi I'm having a strange issue with Rails 4.2 namespaces and routing.

I'm updating from rails 4.0.13 to Rails 4.2.1 and have a namespace route set up like so:

```
namespace :admin do
  get '', to: 'dashboard#index', as: '/'
  get 'denied', to: 'dashboard#denied', as: '/denied'
  get 'blocked', to: 'dashboard#blocked', as: '/blocked'
  get 'approved' => 'dashboard#approved', as: '/approved'
end
```

and a controller at app/controllers/admin/dashboard_controler.rb defined as:

```
class Admin::DashboardController < ApplicationController
   # redacted/not important
```

Once I start my server and hit the '/admin/approved' endpoint the page loads fine. However if I refresh the page I get a 404 and this error:

```
uninitialized constant AdminDashboardController
```

So I checked rails/info/routes and lo and behold the routes are wrong

```
Helper  HTTP Verb   Path    Controller#Action
admin_approved_path GET /admin/approved(.:format)   admin_dashboard#approved
#note the underscore in the Controller#Action column (4th column)
```

Weird. So I restart the server and hit rails/info/routes and the route is now correct!

```
Helper  HTTP Verb   Path    Controller#Action
admin_approved_path GET /admin/approved(.:format)   admin/dashboard#approved
# there's now a slash in Controller#Action
```

I load the page and it works fine but as soon as I reload it I get the same error and checking the route shows that it has once again changed (the slash becomes an underscore). I've looked through the config docs to see if I'm doing something wrong but nothing really jumped out at me.

Also some context: This is a project I inherited from another dev who no longer works on it and it's quite messy and my hunch is there is a config somewhere that's causing this but I've been away from Rails for a bit and am hoping the community can help me stop pulling my hair out! :)

**Update 1**: Just wanted to clarify that the index route always works without issue but the denied, blocked and approved routes are the one that show this strange behavior of working once then magically rewriting the routes controller to something else and failing with uninitialized constant error.

**Update 2**: I just tested Rails 4.1.10 and 4.2.0. The error is not present in 4.1.10 but it is present in 4.2.0. I'm about to dive into actionpack to see if this is a real issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this error went away after adding `render :layout => 'admin'` to the functions powering the bad endpoints. Not sure why that fixes it but it does.

Before fix:

```
def index
  # redacted...
  render :layout => 'admin' # hrm wonder why this always worked *facepalm
end

def denied
  # redacted...
end

def blocked
  # redacted...
end

def approved
  # redacted...
end
```

After fix:

```
def index
  # redacted...
  render :layout => 'admin' # hrm wonder why this always worked *facepalm
end

def denied
  # redacted...
  render :layout => 'admin'
end

def blocked
  # redacted...
  render :layout => 'admin'
end

def approved
  # redacted...
  render :layout => 'admin'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think weird behavior can come from unnecessary overriding methods with :as. Also there are some depreciations in routing since 4.1. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/actionpack/CHANGELOG.md
Try to refactor code in this way:

```
namespace :admin do
  get '/' => 'dashboard#index'
  get '/denied' => 'dashboard#denied'
  get '/blocked' => 'dashboard#blocked'
  get '/approved' => 'dashboard#approved'
end
```

Comment: Tried this and still getting seeing the same issue. The strange part is that the index route always works but the denied, blocked and approved routes are the one that show this strange behavior. Gonna update the main post with this info as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just upgraded 4.1.8 => 4.2.3 and got the same issue.

```
namespace :internet, :path => '/' do
   get 'provider' => 'provider#list', as: :providers
end
```

Request should go to Internet::ProviderController#list , but goes to InternetProviderController

In my case the problem was in this piece of layout:

```
<body class="<%= params[:controller].gsub!('/','_') %>-<%= params[:action] %>">
```

It changes the settings of route. The solution is simple:

```
<body class="<%= params[:controller].gsub('/','_') %>-<%= params[:action] %>">
```